# mysql borra fila "casi" duplicada

Tags: mysql

La cuestión es la siguiente:

```
|  id  |c1|c2| c3 |c4|fecha

817614  01 30 2517 0  2018-05-18 10:02:43

817615  02 30 2517 0  2018-05-18 10:02:46

817616  03 30 2517 0  2018-05-18 10:54:31

817617  04 30 2517 0  2018-05-18 10:54:39

817618  05 30 2554 0  2018-05-18 10:58:20

817619  06 30 2554 0  2018-05-18 10:58:28

817620  07 30 2554 0  2018-05-18 10:58:31

817621  08 30 2517 0  2018-05-18 10:58:54

817622  09 30 2444 0  2018-05-18 11:02:12

817623  10 30 2444 0  2018-05-18 11:02:17

817624  11 30 2444 0  2018-05-18 11:02:19
```

Tengo registros repetidos en todo menos en los segundos de la col Fecha.
Y no puedo usar el distinct.
Como podría hacer para que elimine los registros que están dentro del mismo minuto?
Desde ya muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Podrias aclarar como queres que quede la tabla? que registros queres dejar y cuales queres borrar.. y porque? asi entendemos las reglas

Comment: Ok, deberían quedar estos registros:
817614  01 30 2517 0  2018-05-18 10:02:43

817616  03 30 2517 0  2018-05-18 10:54:31

817616  03 30 2517 0  2018-05-18 10:54:31

817622  09 30 2444 0  2018-05-18 11:02:12

Porque el resto son errores de tiempo por doble marcada en un reloj checkeador.

Comment: borrarlos de la tabla o del resultado del select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para un `SELECT`

```
SELECT * FROM registros
  WHERE id 
  IN (
   SELECT t.id FROM (
     SELECT 
       DATE_FORMAT(r.fecha,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') AS fecha_sin_segundos,
       MIN(r.id) AS id 
     FROM registros r 
     GROUP BY fecha_sin_segundos
    ) AS t
);
```

para un `DELETE` (ojo hacer backup) ponemos un `NOT IN`

```
DELETE FROM registros
  WHERE id 
  NOT IN (
   SELECT t.id FROM (
     SELECT 
       DATE_FORMAT(r.fecha,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') AS fecha_sin_segundos,
       MIN(r.id) AS id 
     FROM registros r 
     GROUP BY fecha_sin_segundos
    ) AS t
);
```

Toma el registro con id menor, si queres conservar/mostrar el id mayor reemplazar el `MIN(r.id)` por `MAX(r.id)`

para hacer un backup y probar la limpieza podes usar lo siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE registros_backup LIKE registros;
INSERT registros_backup SELECT * FROM registros;
```

y trabajas sobre `registros_backup`

**editado:** para tablas con muchos registros tal vez te convenga crear una nueva tabla y copiar los datos en limpio (sumamos el "backup" con el select):

```
CREATE TABLE registros_limpio LIKE registros;
INSERT registros_limpio 
SELECT * FROM registros
  WHERE id 
  IN (
   SELECT t.id FROM (
     SELECT 
       DATE_FORMAT(r.fecha,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') AS fecha_sin_segundos,
       MIN(r.id) AS id 
     FROM registros r 
     GROUP BY fecha_sin_segundos
    ) AS t
);
```

Comment: WOW _____ I M P R S I O N A N T E !!!
Muchísimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Se ve el patrón que cada registro se repite una vez, entonces elimina los id pares. Así solo te quedaría un solo registro, siempre BCK(BACKUP) de tu tabla.

`delete from prueba WHERE mod(id,2) = 0`

Saludos cordiales,

Comment: Está bueno también pero a veces se toma la marcada 1 , 2 3 y hasta 4 veces. Es mas, a veces te marcan la Entrada como Salida, Entrada en el mismo minuto y varias veces... Muchas gracias igualmente. ;)